# JBDI - Eating up part of the SQL statement

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, dropwizard, jdbi

This is my JDBI method

```
@Override
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_CAMPAIGN_ID + " = :campaignId AND " + COLUMN_STATUS
                + " = 0 AND " + COLUMN_STAGE_ID + " IS NULL AND " + COLUMN_MODIFICATION_DATE
                + " < NOW() - INTERVAL '<timeInterval>'")
List<Idea> getDraftIdeasBeforeTime(@Bind("campaignId") long campaignId,
                @Define("timeInterval") String timeInterval);
```

On execution, it breaks with the following error

```
ERROR [2021-10-22 10:06:00,041] com.addons.advanced.jobs.DraftIdeasJob: Exception received while trying to delete draft ideas : org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type timestamp without time zone
  Position: 127 [statement:"SELECT * FROM ideas WHERE campaign_id = :campaignId AND status = 0 AND stage_id IS NULL AND modification_date < NOW() - INTERVAL '<timeInterval>'", located:"SELECT * FROM ideas WHERE campaign_id = :campaignId AND status = 0 AND stage_id IS NULL AND modification_date ", rewritten:"/* IdeasDaoJdbi.getDraftIdeasBeforeTime */ SELECT * FROM ideas WHERE campaign_id = ? AND status = 0 AND stage_id IS NULL AND modification_date ", arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{campaignId:10}, finder:[]}]
```

As you can see, post location, it only considers the up until `... AND modification_date` and ignores what comes after.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `<` (change to `\\<`) symbol in your query since it is the same as used by template engine.

EDIT:
Adding to the answer for more specificity, the issue is at

`" < NOW() - INTERVAL '<timeInterval>'"`

which needs to be

`" \\< NOW() - INTERVAL '<timeInterval>'"`